# C# word automation: copy and paste a table into a new page

Tags: c#, ms-word, paste

I have simplified the problem as follows:
I have a word document with a template table inside. The table has 2 rows including header and 3 columns. I want to keep a copy of template table. Then I fill the original table with data. After that, I wqant to open a new page by inserting a page break and paste the template table into the new page.
My code:

```
string filePath = Application.StartupPath + @"\docs\test.docx";
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
wordApp.Visible = true;

//copy and keep template table
Word.Table templateTable = wordDoc.Tables[1];

//fill the table
Word.Cell cell;
cell = wordDoc.Tables[1].Cell(2, 1);
cell.Range.Text = "First Column...";
cell = wordDoc.Tables[1].Cell(2, 2);
cell.Range.Text = "Second Column...";
cell = wordDoc.Tables[1].Cell(2, 3);
cell.Range.Text = "Third Column...";

//insert a page break
wordDoc.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);

//paste the template table in new page
Word.Range range = templateTable.Range;
range.Copy();
range.SetRange(templateTable.Range.End + 1, templateTable.Range.End + 1);
Word.Table tableCopy = wordDoc.Tables.Add(range, 1, 1, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
tableCopy.Range.Paste();
```

The problem:

1. The filled table is pasted, not the template table
2. The table is pasted after first table not in the new page at the end of document.

I tried several things but cannot figure out how to solve the problem.
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Francesco Baruchelli's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677666/word-interop-c-insert-new-page-using-existing-page?rq=1), I could solve the issue finally:
Solution:

```
string filePath = Application.StartupPath + @"\docs\test.docx";
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
wordApp.Visible = true;
Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection;

//copy and keep template table
var tableToUse = wordDoc.Tables[1];
//copy the empty table in the clipboard
Word.Range range = tableToUse.Range;
range.Copy();

//fill the original table
Word.Cell cell;
cell = wordDoc.Tables[1].Cell(2, 1);
cell.Range.Text = "First Column...";
cell = wordDoc.Tables[1].Cell(2, 2);
cell.Range.Text = "Second Column...";
cell = wordDoc.Tables[1].Cell(2, 3);
cell.Range.Text = "Third Column...";

//inserting a page break: first go to end of document
selection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);
//insert a page break
object breakType = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
selection.InsertBreak(ref breakType);

//paste the template table in new page
//add a new table (initially with 1 row and one column) at the end of the document
Word.Table tableCopy = wordDoc.Tables.Add(selection.Range, 1, 1, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
//paste the original template table over the new one
tableCopy.Range.Paste();
```